# Running file code from Terminal (Starting up a local website)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, terminal

I am trying to use a (mac) terminal to run a folder containing code for starting up a website. I am new to using node.js, and am having difficulty figuring out how to run the entire folder that contains separate js/css/html files. The website code is from the last chapter of the EloquentJS book (link: http://eloquentjavascript.net/21_skillsharing.html). I'm guessing this should be pretty easy to do, but I can't quite seem to figure it out...

The folder name is 'skillsharing', it's saved in 'downloads'. I've tried running "   $node downloads/skillsharing  ", but it doesn't seem to quite work.

Comment: Is there an `app.js` or some main file that handles the server?

Comment: What do you mean running an entire folder ? Serve it for http client ? run every nodejs script into it ? else ?

Comment: There is a file with client-side js and another one with server-side js , among other files. To the extent that I understand the code, I don't think there is a main js file ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node projects there's a file usually named "index.js", "app.js" or "server.js" that is responsible of launching the server and putting it to listen through a specific port. Try: $node thatfile.js

Comment: I tried following your suggestion by just running the server js file through node, yet the webpage still doesn't seem to quite work

Comment: How are you accessing the webpage? Try localhost:8000

Comment: The server is set to listen on port 8000 , so I don't think that's the problem../

Comment: Yes, I saw it in the code of http://eloquentjavascript.net/21_skillsharing.html. So you're running a node server on port 8000 and you see nothing when you enter  "localhost:8000" in your browser?

Comment: The following comes up: {"serverTime":1437323847686,"talks":[]} ,

Comment: That's supposed to appear according to "{"serverTime": 1405438911833,
 "talks": [{"title": "Unituning",
            "presenter": "Carlos",
            "summary": "Modifying your cycle for extra style",
            "comment": []}]}".                                                                           I think you have no idea of what you're doing. I can't help you anymore.

Comment: ^ I'm guessing the fact that the page displays at least something is already better than it being absolutely unresponsive. However, this is still far from what the page is supposed to do, and since the issue here is unlikely to be in the file codes, it must be related to how i'm running the code...

Comment: No, I guarantee it's not about how you're running the code. The problem, if there's any, is that you don't understand the code.

Comment: OK. I really appreciate the effort though, thank you thenchanter.

Comment: No problem. You might want to recheck the routes in your code.